# How to expose JSTL custom tag value

Tags: jstl

The following class is the implementation of a custom tag.

```
public class TextColorTag extends TagSupport {

    private String var;
    //getters & setters

    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
         String color = "#eee";
         setValue(var, color);
         JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
         out.print(color);
    }
```

Later in my jsp, when I try to use textColor I find it empty

```
the color is: <bv:textColor var="textColor" />    <!-- Ok!, display #eee -->

the color is: ${textColor} <!-- Ko!, empty. Why? -->
```

Of course in the tld I have declared an attribute var.

How to expose the result of the custom tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the response in javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.ConditionalTagSupport

To expose variables, replace the following:

```
setValue(var, color);
```

By

```
pageContext.setAttribute(var, color);
```